# How to access a shared file based on its ID from another user account with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm working on an iOS application where where one user (the owner) can share a directory, then the directory ID is communicated to another user (the subscriber), who is running the same application on its own device. Both users have distinct Google accounts. For now, the application uses the full drive scope (kGTLAuthScopeDrive).

On the owner side, I create the directory:

```
GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
folder.title = name;
folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject: folder uploadParameters: nil];

[_service executeQuery: query completionHandler: completion];
```

Add a subscriber-related permission on it:

```
GTLDrivePermission *permission = [GTLDrivePermission new];

permission.value = subscriberEmail;
permission.type = @"user";
permission.role = @"writer";

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForPermissionsInsertWithObject: permission fileId: directory.identifier];

query.sendNotificationEmails = NO;

[_service executeQuery: query completionHandler: completion];
```

On the subscriber side, once the shared directory ID is received:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId: sharedFolderID];

[_service executeQuery: query completionHandler: completion];
```

The issue is that I always get a 404 error when accessing the shared directory on the subscriber side.

If I do a Files.get request using the API explorer, while being logged with the subscriber account, the request succeeds though.

Also with the code above, if I change permission.type to 'anyone', the problem vanishes, but this is not really a solution.

Am I doing something wrong or is this unsupported currently with the iOS SDK? If this is case, is there another way to support this sharing model?

Comment: Did you find an answer in the several months since you posted?